# Protothread co-routine : send concatenated boolean to macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a specific need, in a special context.
I'd like to make my code more clear.

I'm working on making protothread on embedded system

I have to wait on a process.

To wait, we call a macro :
`PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(params);`

So for example, my line can be :

```
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&actual_state.et_wait) || ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_RECEIVED || ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_SEND);
```

This macro make my program wait until one of those conditions are true (so when `etimer_expired(&actual_state.et_wait)`  is true or  `ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_RECEIVED`  is true or `ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_SEND` is true

This condition come true if an other thread says (for example): hey a packet got received !

My events that i need to wait are defined by flags :

```
if ( (actual_state.wait_event & TIMER) != 0 )
     PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&actual_state.et_wait))
if ( (actual_state.wait_event & PACKET_RECEIVED) != 0 )
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL( ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_RECEIVED)
if ( (actual_state.wait_event & PACKET_SEND) != 0 )
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL( ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_SEND)
```

if i have several flags defined, i'm doing :

```
    if ( (actual_state.wait_event & PACKET_RECEIVED) != 0 && (actual_state.wait_event & PACKET_SEND) != 0 )
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL( ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_SEND ||  ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_RECEIVED);
```

But i have to do that for every combinaison.

Is there a way to not write every possibilites ? and write something like that :
`PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(wait);`

Thanks.

Edit : here all my macro definition
It's a co-routine, so I can't pre-compute the boolean value (multi-threading)

```
#define PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(c) PROCESS_YIELD_UNTIL(c)

#define PROCESS_YIELD_UNTIL(c)      PT_YIELD_UNTIL(process_pt, c)

#define PT_YIELD_UNTIL(pt, cond)        \
  do {                      \
    PT_YIELD_FLAG = 0;              \
    LC_SET((pt)->lc);               \
    if((PT_YIELD_FLAG == 0) || !(cond)) {   \
      return PT_YIELDED;            \
    }                       \
  } while(0)
```

Comment: Just do it with a another flag, and use 'or' to 'or' it on the flag.

Comment: I have 18 flag. Can't make flags for all combinaison ! Or maybe i didn't get your answer

Comment: `wait += || etimer_expired(&actual_state.et_wait)` this is all kinds of wrong, and not at all how you incrementally build a boolean condition.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you construct your bool variable, since a bool variable can be plugged anywhere a logical expression can, even hidden withing a macro. But it's guesswork since you didn't specify exactly how it *"doesn't work"*.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know that's why i used comment. It was to show what i would like to do. I'll edit to explain more.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you have to test some variables in that macro, you have to - well - test those variables in the macro. But without knowing what the macro actually does and what you want, how are we supposed to help? (let apart the code-snippets you show are plain wrong; if you think different, there might be major missconception and more to learn about the C language)

Comment: Erm, there is no loop here. That `do {} while(0);` thing is a kludge to make the macro look like a proper statement with a semicolon, without it being illegal syntax.

Comment: @Olaf you are totally right. I'm far to be an expert for C language and have a lot to learn. However, i think for this case it's about not enough explanation. I edited my question, thanks for your time.

Comment: I still don't see how this macro tests permanently tests the conditions. It just  tests them once, but does not seem to wait if none is true. Looks more like some coop-multithreading which makes things more complicated. Maybe you need your own loop around that macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to plug an expression into the macro, you are stuck with a ternary expression to take the flags into account.

```
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL((actual_state.wait_event & TIMER ? etimer_expired(&actual_state.et_wait) : false) ||
                         (actual_state.wait_event & PACKET_RECEIVED ? ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_RECEIVED : false) ||
                         (actual_state.wait_event & PACKET_SEND ? ev == PROCESS_EVENT_PACKET_SEND : false));
```

This is just ugly, I agree. You'd better spend your time writing a function that accepts the parameters and return a truth value, like Klas Lindbäck suggested.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. Great information, but knew it. But still thanks a lot. So how you define the variable ?

Comment: But if i do that the boolean is computed, isn't it ?

Comment: @LudovicGuerra, of course. Why shouldn't it be calculated in advance? The macro only uses it once in its expansion.

Comment: With the macro shown, the problem looks more complicated. I suspect you in fact have to test the conditions inside the macro, thus **cannot** pre-calculate the value. That seems to be some "lightweight" cooperative multitasking (similar to co-routines).

Comment: I see, so no choice but to pass some expression into the macro.

Comment: @olaf to be more precise I borrow heavily on Tatham's co-routine : http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

Comment: @LudovicGuerra: Problem is we need the whole concept, but imo that is too broad for this site. You need more of a discussion forum to get step-by-step help. That's off-topic here.

Comment: @StoryTeller it's seems a really good idea ! It's by far better than having to write all posibilities (I have 18 flags).

Comment: @Olaf Thanks you to you and to Story for your great help. And I'm really sorry to not have well explained my problems. The ternair condition seems a good idea, didn't think about it ! 
I should have explained more in depth my problems, since is not about my code not working but about how to make it shorter and smarter. Thanks

Comment: I still think you can use log-ops only. But I'm too lazy to figure out. A function would require global variables and/or uniform evaluation which I don't see from the information shown. Anyway, the whole thing looks suspect to me.

Comment: What do you mean by  log-ops ?

Comment: **log**ical operators. As opposed to **bit**wise-ops or the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and pass the address of all variables involved:

```
bool myfunc(STATE* actual_state, int* ev) {
  bool wait;
  /* add your logic evaluation here and set wait */
  return wait;
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(myfunc(&actual_state, &ev));
```

Comment: Thanks you but doesn't answer. I must not evaluate the bool (so not calculate the final bool, jsut send the big condition to the macro)

Comment: I don't see any mention of `volatile`. Let apart they are normally not appropriate for multi-threaded systems. E.g. there is no guarantee they are atomic.

Comment: @Olaf The OP doesn't specify the mechanism behind the macro. It is quite possible that `volatile` is superfluous.

Comment: @LudovicGuerra Packing it into a function will make a new calculation of `wait` every time the macro evaluates the expression. If that doesn't work with your macro, then I recommend StoryTellers answer.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: So your answer is based on plain speculation. And I did not mean superfluous, but insufficient, because of being not "strong" enough. Never rely on `volatile` for multi-core multithreaded systems. Things can be different for embedded/single code systems, but that is a matter of the specific execution environment.

Comment: @Olaf That `volatile` isn't strong enough may be true in the general case. In this case, howeever, it was clear that if further synchronization was needed it had to be handled by the macro and not by the caller since there was no synchronization in the examples. Given the actual macro definition it is clear that `volatile` is superfluous.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: When I wrote this there was not enough information given. Thus the "not strong enough". Anyway, it is better to use atomics. Iff a `volatile` really is sufficient, the atomics will result in the same code - nothing lost. Just use the standard features and avoid homebrew hacks where possible & reasonable.